# Julia lang: MethodError: no method matching sqrt(::Vector{ComplexF64})

Tags: julia

My code:

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("PyPlot")
using PyPlot 
e = 0.0
eta = 1e - 4
wmin = -2.0
wmax = 2.0
Nw = 1000
w =range(wmin, wmax, Nw)
g = 1 ./ (w .- e .+ eta * im)
t = 1.0

g2 = g .^2

Gsemi = (1 ./ (g*2*t^2)) .* (1 .- sqrt(1 .- 4*t^2*g .^2)) //Error line
Ginf = Gsemi ./ (1 .- Gsemi .^ 2 * t^2)
xlabel(L"Energy $\omega $", fontsize=20)
ylabel("Density of states", fontsize=20)
axis([-2,2,0,1.4])
plot(w, (-1.0/pi)*imag(Ginf), linewidth=3.0)
```

The error message:

[image: Error display]

How can I fix this? sorry my english is bad, thank for anwers

Comment: Please also mention what you want the line of code to do. Fixing it will be easier if we know the intent of that line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular error happens because you cannot take the square root of a vector, since it does not make sense mathematically.

But you *can* take the square root of each element separately. To do that add a dot to the `sqrt` function call:

```
sqrt.(1 .- 4*t^2*g .^2)
```

But you should really add more dots on that line to save some temporary allocations. You can do that with the `@.` macro instead of dotting everything by hand, like this:

```
Gsemi = @. (1 / (g*2*t^2) * (1 - sqrt(1 - 4*t^2*g^2)))
```

Now, all operations will be element-wise.

Also, make sure to put your code inside a function.